# Definition of $\nabla T$ where $T \in \mathcal{D\,}'(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, $T \in \mathcal{D\,}'(\Omega)$ a distribution i.e. a linear and continous functional on test function space $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$. I came across the following definition of $\nabla T$:

$$\langle\nabla T,\phi\rangle:=-\langle T,\nabla\phi\rangle \;\; \text{for every} \;\; \phi \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega).$$

This definition confuses me because $\nabla \phi$ is a vector valued function and $T$ should act on scalar valued functions as $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ elements.

---

The context is integration by parts. After the definition follow:

if $T=T_u$ with $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ then we have

$$\int_\Omega (\nabla u) \phi dx=-\int_\Omega u (\nabla \phi) dx \;\; \text{for every} \;\; \phi \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$$
which is a particular case of the definition.

Comment: It means that for all vector, $\nabla _v T$ is defined as $\langle  \nabla _v T, \phi\rangle := -\langle T, \nabla _v\phi\rangle$.

Comment: Or in terms of components: 
$$\langle \partial_i T, \phi \rangle = - \langle T, \partial_i \phi \rangle, \quad i=1,\ldots,n$$